# SQL Workbench/J customizing keyword highlighting not working?

Tags: keyword, sql-workbench-j

I followed the instructions in http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/editor.html#editor-custom-keywords and created a txt file "keywords.db" in my config file and added a keyword, but it still doesn't highlight in editor? Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "in my config *directory*" rather than "file":

The file needs to have the extension **`.wb`**, not `.db`

Comment: I should clarify: 1) yes it is in config directory .sqlworkbench, 2) yes, the filename is "keywords.wb" 3) I only have one word in the keywords.wb file, "LIMIT" with no quotes and LIMIT does not highlight in my editor